# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x46 in tid 6643 (FinalizerDaemon) when closing map

Tags: android, debugging, cyanogenmod

I'm get an error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x46 in tid 6643 (FinalizerDaemon)` every time I'm closing map activity.

Here is the logcat.

```
07-10 14:14:52.256    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'samsung/cm_golden/golden:5.1.1/LMY47V/055cd3a75f:userdebug/test-keys'
07-10 14:14:52.256    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '106'
07-10 14:14:52.256    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
07-10 14:14:52.256    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 6633, tid: 6643, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> net.gumcode.smarthospital <<<
07-10 14:14:52.257    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x46
07-10 14:14:52.269    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 0000000a  r1 40522558  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 4258ac00  r5 405225b4  r6 40529c0c  r7 00000000
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 46e75aac  r9 42429000  sl 22d58d90  fp 230bfe80
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 40529dac  sp 46e75a70  lr 40506b9b  pc 4050cacc  cpsr 60070030
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 0002eacc  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::GLConsumer::~GLConsumer()+35)
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 0002eb45  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::GLConsumer::~GLConsumer()+4)
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 0000e001  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+40)
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 0005ee4f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::sp<android::IGraphicBufferProducer>::~sp()+18)
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 00092da7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07-10 14:14:52.270    1661-1661/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 000003df  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

I've been thinking what possibly cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in the dynamic library /system/lib/libgui.so, it seems that it causes a segmentation fault. I don't know if there is much to do to solve that.